# R script how to substitute values in dataset from other dataset

Tags: r, dataset, substitution

I am having trouble with the data manipulation in R. I have this dataset (example)

```
  df <- data.frame(GRP = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,4),
     x=c("x1","x1","x1","x2","x2","x2","x2"),y=c(3,8,2,20,24,28,31))

   GRP  x  y
   1   x1  3
   2   x1  8
   3   x1  2
   1   x2 20
   2   x2 24
   3   x2 28
   4   x2 31
```

and would like to transform this dataset into

```
  GRP  x1  x2
  1    3   20
  2    8   24
  3    2   28
  4    0   31
```

I tried:

```
 df1 <- expand.grid(GRP = unique(df$GRP), x1=0, x2=0)
 df1$x1[df1$GRP %in% df$GRP]<- df$y[df1$GRP %in% df$GRP &
                     df$x %in% c("x1")]
 df1$x2[df1$GRP %in% df$GRP]<- df$y[df1$GRP %in% df$GRP & df$x %in% 
             c("x2")]
```

and get this is a result:

```
 GRP x1 x2
  1  3 20
  2  8 24
  3  2 28
  4  3 31
```

Any suggestions how to tackle this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to transform the data from `long` to `wide`, these are some options

```
library(reshape2)
 dcast(df, GRP~x, value.var='y', fill=0)
 #   GRP x1 x2
 #1   1  3 20
 #2   2  8 24
 #3   3  2 28
 #4   4  0 31
```

Or

```
xtabs(y~GRP+x, df)
```

Or

```
library(tidyr)
spread(df, x,y, fill=0)
```

Also, for the substituting of values in 'df1' from 'df', may be this helps

```
 df1 <- data.frame(GRP=unique(df$GRP), x1=0, x2=0)
 indx1 <- df$x=='x1' & df$GRP %in% df1$GRP
 indx2 <- df$x=='x2' & df$GRP %in% df1$GRP
 df1$x1[df1$GRP%in% df$GRP[indx1]] <- df$y[indx1]
 df1$x2[df1$GRP%in% df$GRP[indx2]] <- df$y[indx2]
 df1
 #  GRP x1 x2
 #1   1  3 20
 #2   2  8 24
 #3   3  2 28
 #4   4  0 31
```

#### Update

Suppose, if the order of rows in 'df1' are different

```
 df1 <- data.frame(GRP=unique(df$GRP), x1=0, x2=0)
 df1 <- df1[order(-df1$GRP),]
 indx1 <- df$x=='x1' & df$GRP %in% df1$GRP
 indx2 <- df$x=='x2' & df$GRP %in% df1$GRP
 df1$x1[match(df$GRP[indx1], df1$GRP)] <- df$y[indx1]
 df1$x2[match(df$GRP[indx2], df1$GRP)] <- df$y[indx2]
 df1
 #  GRP x1 x2
 #4   4  0 31
 #3   3  2 28
 #2   2  8 24
 #1   1  3 20
```

It also works with other order of rows, starting with the original 'df1'

```
 set.seed(28) 
 df1 <- df1[sample(nrow(df1)),]
```

gives the output after running the codes listed above

```
 df1
 #  GRP x1 x2
 #1   1  3 20
 #4   4  0 31
 #3   3  2 28
 #2   2  8 24
```

Comment: Great thanks. This is very helpful for me and what if the rows for column GRP are not in the same order e.g if I do first df1 <- df1[order(-df1$GRP),]. How do you ensure that the values are being substituted in the correct rows?

Comment: @kingvodka1 use `match` instead of `%in%`.  BTW, this is easier to do with `reshape`, `spread`, I don't understand the reason for this extra effort